Implementation of an Ordered Character Class #2
Overview
This is a follow-up review request incorporating commented from the following prior review: Implementation of an Ordered Character Class. I have incorporated many of the suggestions made by Toby Speight as well as some additional changes.
I think the outcome of the review has resulted in less code that is more flexible and easier to understand.
As before this code  is my attempt a solving a problem that came up in one of my projects. I needed a type that could be constrained to a defined list of characters, be set to a specific character, and be able to be incremented / decremented to the following / proceeding character.
There are two files included in this post:

ordered_char.h
test_main.cc

The first is the header and, as this is now a class template, includes the implementation.  The second file provides examples of usage and test cases.
Changes from Prior Review
I have attempted to correct all of the spelling and typo issues in the comments and documentation.
Interface

The class is now a template on the character type can can support various character types such as char or wchar_t
There is now only a single constructor with no optional parameters
The constructor is marked explicit
All of optional parameters and parameters that resulted in multiple constructors have been turned into setters
A conversion operator has been added to allow for directly converting an object of this class into the a character of the templated type based on the current value of the object, this is similar to calling the GetChar() method
HasUniqueChars() and FindCharIndex() were modified to act on the object instead of taking a parameter

Implementation

The constructor uses initializers rather than assignment
Error strings for the exceptions are now in an anonymous namespace as recommended during the review
HasUniqueChars(), FindCharIndex(), and IsMember() were modified as recommended to make better use of library features rather than implementing my own algorithms
Two new private methods were added NextIndex() and PrevIndex() so that redundant code could be eliminated from Pred() and Succ() as well as the pre/post increment/decrement operators

Tests
Testing is the area in which I have made the least improvement.  I have reorganize the test code to be a bit cleaner and better named.  New functionality has had testing added.  The test code now reports PASS or FAIL for each test as well as at a summary level.
There are currently no tests for character types other than char.
I have not had the time to investigate an sort of test framework.  I think I will want to do so before beginning my next project.
Review Request
I would like to have this code reviewed for general feedback, including if I have properly interpreted feedback from the prior review.
There are two c++ firsts for me in this update.  This is the first class template I have written.  Have I implemented it correctly?  Are there additional consideration that I have missed?  The second is that this is the first time I have implemented a conversion operator.  Have I done so correctly?  Are there any gotchas I should be aware of?
Compiling the Code
I have compiled the code on Linux with the following command:
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic  
-Warray-bounds -Wmissing-braces -Wconversion -Wuseless-cast -Weffc++ 
test_main.cc -o test_main

No warnings or errors are reported.
ordered_char.h
#ifndef H_BURNINGLOGIC_ORDERED_CHAR
#define H_BURNINGLOGIC_ORDERED_CHAR

/** \file ordered_char.h
    \brief Header for the OrderedChar class (a header only class)
*/

#include <cstddef>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

namespace BurningLogic {

/** \class OrderedChar
 * The OrderedChar class template provides a character that can be incremented or
 * decremented from a provided discrete ordered list of characters. The object can
 * optionally clamp at the ends of the provided list or  wrap-around. It is an error to
 * instantiate an object with an empty character list or one with characters that
 * appear more then once.  CharT is a character type.
 */
template <class CharT>
class OrderedChar {
 public:
  /**
   * Constructor for OrderedChar objects.  Requires specifying an ordered list of possible
   * characters which must be unique.  The default value of the OrderedChar object is the
   * first value of char_string (char_string[0]).
   * @param char_string a string containing, in order, the representable characters
   * @exception std::invalid_argument char_string is empty
   * @exception std::invalid_argument char_string contains duplicate characters
   */

  explicit OrderedChar(std::basic_string_view<CharT> char_string);

  /**
   * Returns the current value of the character.
   * @return the current value of the OrderedChar object
   */
  CharT GetChar(void) const;

  /**
   * Sets the current value to the specified character.  It is an error to
   * specify a character that is not part of the object's character list.
   * @param c the character value to set the OrderedChar object to
   * @exception std::invalid_argument the character is not a member of the object's character list
   */
  void SetChar(CharT c);

  /**
   * Enables or disables clamping to the beginning or end of the character list when the object
   * value is decremented or incremented.  If clamping is disabled then the character list will
   * wrap around from the beginning to end or end to beginning.  The default is for clamping to be
   * disabled.
   * @param clamp true to clamp at the extremes or false for values to wrap around at the extremes
   */
  void SetClamp(bool clamp);

  /**
   * Returns the predecessor to the object's current character value.  If the object is at the
   * beginning of the character list and clamping is enabled it returns the first character in
   * the list.  If the object is at the beginning of the list and clamping is not enabled then
   * the call will "wrap-around" and return the last character in the list.
   */
  CharT Pred(void) const;

  /**
   * Returns the successor to the object's current character value.  If the object is at the end
   * of the character list and clamping is enabled it returns the last character in the list. If
   * the object is at the end of the list and clamping is not enabled then the call will
   * "wrap-around" and return the first character in the list.
   */
  CharT Succ(void) const;

  /**
   * Checks if the specified character is in the objects character list.
   * @param c the character value to check if in the object's character list
   * @return true if the character is in the object's character list and false otherwise
   */
  bool IsMember(CharT c) const;

  /**
   * Prefix increment operator.  Increments the character value of the OrderedChar object.
   * If the object is at the end of the character list and clamping is enabled the value of
   * the object is unchanged.  If the object is at the end of the list and clamping is not
   * enabled then value will "wrap-around" and object value will be set to the first
   * character in the list.
   * @return the value of the object before it is incremented
   */
  OrderedChar& operator++();

  /**
   * Prefix decrement operator.  Decrements the character value of the OrderedChar object.
   * If the object is at the beginning of the character list and clamping is enabled the value
   * of the object is unchanged.  If the object is at the beginning of the list and clamping
   * is not enabled then value will "wrap-around" and object value will be set to the last
   * character in the list.
   * @return the value of the object before it is decremented
   */
  OrderedChar& operator--();

  /**
   * Postfix increment operator.  Increments the character value of the OrderedChar object.
   * If the object is at the end of the character list and clamping is enabled the value of the
   * object is unchanged.  If the object is at the end of the list and clamping is not enabled
   * then value will "wrap-around" and object value will be set to the first character in the
   * list.
   * @return the value of the object after it is incremented
   */
  OrderedChar operator++(int);

  /**
   * Postfix decrement operator.  Decrements the character value of the OrderedChar object.
   * If the object is at the beginning of the character list and clamping is enabled the value
   * of the object is unchanged.  If the object is at the beginning of the list and clamping
   * is not enabled then value will "wrap-around" and object value will be set to the last
   * character in the list.
   * @return the value of the object after it is incremented
   */
  OrderedChar operator--(int);

  /**
   * Conversion operator.  Allows for implicit conversion of the object current value to
   * the character type is was created with.
   */
  operator CharT() const;

 private:
  std::basic_string<CharT> cs_ = "\0";
  std::size_t index_ = 0;
  bool clamp_ = false;

  bool HasUniqueChars(void) const;
  std::size_t FindCharIndex(CharT c) const;
  std::size_t NextIndex(void) const;
  std::size_t PrevIndex(void) const;
};

}  // namespace BurningLogic

// Implementation follows
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Anonymous namespace so these are not visible to the linker outside of this file
namespace {

const std::string empty_char_string_text = "char_string must be non-empty";
const std::string invalid_char_string_text = "char_string must entries must be unique";
const std::string char_not_found_text = "inital_char not found in char_string";

}  // namespace

namespace BurningLogic {

template <class CharT>
OrderedChar<CharT>::OrderedChar(std::basic_string_view<CharT> char_string) : cs_{char_string} {
  if (cs_.empty()) {
    throw std::invalid_argument(empty_char_string_text);
  }

  if (HasUniqueChars()) {
    cs_ = char_string;
  } else {
    throw std::invalid_argument(invalid_char_string_text);
  }
}

template <class CharT>
CharT OrderedChar<CharT>::GetChar(void) const {
  return cs_[index_];
}

template <class CharT>
void OrderedChar<CharT>::SetChar(CharT c) {
  index_ = FindCharIndex(c);
}

template <class CharT>
void OrderedChar<CharT>::SetClamp(bool clamp) {
  clamp_ = clamp;
}

template <class CharT>
CharT OrderedChar<CharT>::Pred(void) const {
  return cs_[PrevIndex()];
}

template <class CharT>
CharT OrderedChar<CharT>::Succ(void) const {
  return cs_[NextIndex()];
}

template <class CharT>
bool OrderedChar<CharT>::IsMember(CharT c) const {
  return cs_.find(c) != std::basic_string<CharT>::npos;
}

template <class CharT>
OrderedChar<CharT>& OrderedChar<CharT>::operator++() {
  index_ = NextIndex();
  return *this;
}

template <class CharT>
OrderedChar<CharT>& OrderedChar<CharT>::operator--() {
  index_ = PrevIndex();
  return *this;
}

template <class CharT>
OrderedChar<CharT> OrderedChar<CharT>::operator++(int) {
  OrderedChar tmp = *this;
  ++*this;
  return tmp;
}

template <class CharT>
OrderedChar<CharT> OrderedChar<CharT>::operator--(int) {
  OrderedChar tmp = *this;
  --*this;
  return tmp;
}

template <class CharT>
OrderedChar<CharT>::operator CharT() const {
  return cs_[index_];
}

template <class CharT>
bool OrderedChar<CharT>::HasUniqueChars(void) const {
  std::map<CharT, std::size_t> histogram;

  for (auto c : cs_) {
    ++histogram[c];

    if (histogram[c] > 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

template <class CharT>
std::size_t OrderedChar<CharT>::FindCharIndex(CharT c) const {
  auto index = cs_.find(c);

  if (index == cs_.npos) {
    throw std::invalid_argument(char_not_found_text);
  }

  return index;
}

template <class CharT>
std::size_t OrderedChar<CharT>::NextIndex(void) const {
  if (index_ != (cs_.length() - 1)) {
    return index_ + 1;
  } else {
    if (clamp_) {
      return index_;  // Clamped at end and unchanged
    } else {
      return 0;  // Wraps around
    }
  }
}

template <class CharT>
std::size_t OrderedChar<CharT>::PrevIndex(void) const {
  if (index_ != 0) {
    return index_ - 1;
  } else {
    if (clamp_) {
      return index_;  // Clamped at beginning and unchanged
    } else {
      return cs_.length() - 1;  // Wraps around
    }
  }
}

}  // namespace BurningLogic

#endif

test_main.cc
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

#include "ordered_char.h"

using namespace BurningLogic;

bool EvalPassFailCaseChar(std::string_view text, char test_char, char expected_char) {
  bool pass = (test_char == expected_char);

  if (pass) {
    std::cout << "PASS: ";
  } else {
    std::cout << "FAIL: ";
  }

  std::cout << text << " = '" << test_char << "' expected '" << expected_char << "'\n";

  return pass;
}

std::string BoolToString(bool b) {
  if (b) {
    return "TRUE";
  } else {
    return "FALSE";
  }
}

bool EvalPassFailCaseBool(std::string_view text, bool test_bool, bool expected_bool) {
  bool pass = (test_bool == expected_bool);

  if (pass) {
    std::cout << "PASS: ";
  } else {
    std::cout << "FAIL: ";
  }

  std::cout << text << " = '" << BoolToString(test_bool) << "' expected '" << BoolToString(expected_bool)
            << "'\n";

  return pass;
}

bool TestValidConstructor(void) {
  bool caught = false;

  std::cout << "\nTest with Valid Constructor\n";
  std::cout << "---------------------------\n";

  try {
    OrderedChar<char> oc("abc123zyx");
  }

  catch (std::invalid_argument &e) {
    std::cout << "FAIL: Caught '" << e.what() << "' \n";
    caught = true;
  }

  if (!caught) {
    std::cout << "PASS\n";
  }

  return !caught;
}

bool TestEmptyStringConstructor(void) {
  bool caught = false;

  std::cout << "\nTest with Empty String Constructor\n";
  std::cout << "----------------------------------\n";

  try {
    OrderedChar<char> oc("");
  }

  catch (std::invalid_argument &e) {
    std::cout << "PASS: Caught '" << e.what() << "' (Expected)\n";
    caught = true;
  }

  if (!caught) {
    std::cout << "FAIL\n";
  }

  return caught;
}

bool TestDuplicateCharConstructor(void) {
  bool caught = false;

  std::cout << "\nTest with Duplicate Char Constructor\n";
  std::cout << "------------------------------------\n";

  try {
    OrderedChar<char> oc("lcnwnciwuenuuj");
  }

  catch (std::invalid_argument &e) {
    std::cout << "PASS: Caught '" << e.what() << "' (Expected)\n";
    caught = true;
  }

  if (!caught) {
    std::cout << "FAIL\n";
  }

  return caught;
}

bool TestMiscFunctions(void) {
  // Test GetChar, SetChar, Pred, Succ, and IsMember
  bool caught = false;
  char test_char;
  bool test_bool;
  bool cumulative_pass = true;

  std::cout << "\nMisc Tests\n";
  std::cout << "----------\n";

  try {
    OrderedChar<char> oc_no_clamp("abcdefghijklm");

    std::cout << "      oc_no_clamp.SetChar('e')\n";
    oc_no_clamp.SetChar('e');
    test_char = oc_no_clamp.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_no_clamp.GetChar()", test_char, 'e');

    test_bool = oc_no_clamp.IsMember('f');
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseBool("oc_no_clamp.IsMember('f')", test_bool, true);

    test_bool = oc_no_clamp.IsMember('7');
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseBool("oc_no_clamp.IsMember('7')", test_bool, false);

    oc_no_clamp.SetChar('a');
    test_char = oc_no_clamp.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_no_clamp.GetChar()", test_char, 'a');

    test_char = oc_no_clamp.Pred();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_no_clamp.Pred()", test_char, 'm');

    test_char = oc_no_clamp.Succ();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_no_clamp.Succ()", test_char, 'b');

    oc_no_clamp.SetChar('m');
    test_char = oc_no_clamp.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_no_clamp.GetChar()", test_char, 'm');

    test_char = oc_no_clamp.Pred();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_no_clamp.Pred()", test_char, 'l');

    test_char = oc_no_clamp.Succ();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_no_clamp.Succ()", test_char, 'a');

    OrderedChar<char> oc_clamp("qwertyuiop");
    oc_clamp.SetClamp(true);

    std::cout << "      oc_clamp.SetChar('t')\n";
    oc_clamp.SetChar('t');
    test_char = oc_clamp.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_clamp.GetChar()", test_char, 't');

    test_bool = oc_clamp.IsMember('r');
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseBool("oc_clamp.IsMember('r')", test_bool, true);

    test_bool = oc_clamp.IsMember('a');
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseBool("oc_clamp.IsMember('a')", test_bool, false);

    oc_clamp.SetChar('q');
    test_char = oc_clamp.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_clamp.GetChar()", test_char, 'q');

    test_char = oc_clamp.Pred();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_clamp.Pred()", test_char, 'q');

    test_char = oc_clamp.Succ();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_clamp.Succ()", test_char, 'w');

    oc_clamp.SetChar('p');
    test_char = oc_clamp.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_clamp.GetChar()", test_char, 'p');

    test_char = oc_clamp.Pred();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_clamp.Pred()", test_char, 'o');

    test_char = oc_clamp.Succ();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_clamp.Succ()", test_char, 'p');

  }

  catch (std::invalid_argument &e) {
    caught = true;
  }

  if (caught) {
    std::cout << "FAIL: One or more exceptions thrown\n";
    cumulative_pass = false;
  }

  return cumulative_pass;
}

bool TestIncrementDecrementWrap(void) {
  bool caught = false;
  bool cumulative_pass = true;
  char test_char;

  std::cout << "\nTest Increment and Decrement without Clamping\n";
  std::cout << "---------------------------------------------\n";

  try {
    OrderedChar<char> oc("abcdefghijklm");
    oc.SetClamp(false);

    // In the middle, decrement
    std::cout << "      oc.SetChar('e')\n";
    oc.SetChar('e');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'e');

    test_char = oc--.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc--.GetChar()", test_char, 'e');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'd');

    test_char = (--oc).GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("(--oc).GetChar()", test_char, 'c');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'c');

    // In the middle, increment
    std::cout << "      oc.SetChar('e')\n";
    oc.SetChar('e');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'e');

    test_char = oc++.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc++.GetChar()", test_char, 'e');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'f');

    test_char = (++oc).GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("(++oc).GetChar()", test_char, 'g');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'g');

    // At the beginning, decrement
    std::cout << "      oc.SetChar('a')\n";
    oc.SetChar('a');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'a');

    test_char = oc--.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc--.GetChar", test_char, 'a');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'm');

    std::cout << "      oc.SetChar('a')\n";
    oc.SetChar('a');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'a');

    test_char = (--oc).GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("(--oc).GetChar()", test_char, 'm');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'm');

    // At the end, increment
    std::cout << "      oc.SetChar('a')\n";
    oc.SetChar('m');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'm');

    test_char = oc++.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc++.GetChar", test_char, 'm');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'a');

    std::cout << "      oc.SetChar('a')\n";
    oc.SetChar('m');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'm');

    test_char = (++oc).GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("(++oc).GetChar", test_char, 'a');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'a');
  }

  catch (std::invalid_argument &e) {
    caught = true;
  }

  if (caught) {
    std::cout << "FAIL: One or more exceptions thrown\n";
    cumulative_pass = false;
  }

  if (cumulative_pass) {
    std::cout << "PASS\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "FAIL: One or more cases failed\n";
  }

  return cumulative_pass;
}

bool TestIncrementDecrementClamp(void) {
  bool caught = false;
  bool cumulative_pass = true;
  char test_char;

  std::cout << "\nTest Increment and Decrement with Clamping\n";
  std::cout << "------------------------------------------\n";

  try {
    OrderedChar<char> oc("abcdefghijklm");
    oc.SetClamp(true);

    // In the middle, decrement
    std::cout << "      oc.SetChar('e')\n";
    oc.SetChar('e');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'e');

    test_char = oc--.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc--.GetChar()", test_char, 'e');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'd');

    test_char = (--oc).GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("(--oc).GetChar()", test_char, 'c');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'c');

    // In the middle, increment
    std::cout << "      oc.SetChar('e')\n";
    oc.SetChar('e');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'e');

    test_char = oc++.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc++.GetChar()", test_char, 'e');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'f');

    test_char = (++oc).GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("(++oc).GetChar()", test_char, 'g');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'g');

    // At the beginning, decrement
    std::cout << "      oc.SetChar('a')\n";
    oc.SetChar('a');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'a');

    test_char = oc--.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc--.GetChar", test_char, 'a');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'a');

    std::cout << "      oc.SetChar('a')\n";
    oc.SetChar('a');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'a');

    test_char = (--oc).GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("(--oc).GetChar()", test_char, 'a');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'a');

    // At the end, increment
    std::cout << "      oc.SetChar('a')\n";
    oc.SetChar('m');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'm');

    test_char = oc++.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc++.GetChar", test_char, 'm');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'm');

    std::cout << "      oc.SetChar('a')\n";
    oc.SetChar('m');
    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'm');

    test_char = (++oc).GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("(++oc).GetChar", test_char, 'm');

    test_char = oc.GetChar();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'm');
  }

  catch (std::invalid_argument &e) {
    caught = true;
  }

  if (caught) {
    std::cout << "FAIL: One or more exceptions thrown\n";
    cumulative_pass = false;
  }

  if (cumulative_pass) {
    std::cout << "PASS\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "FAIL: One or more cases failed\n";
  }

  return cumulative_pass;
}

bool TestConversion(void) {
  bool caught = false;
  bool cumulative_pass = true;
  char test_char;

  std::cout << "\nTest Conversion\n";
  std::cout << "---------------\n";

  try {
    OrderedChar<char> oc("abcdefghijklm");
    oc.SetClamp(true);
    oc.SetChar('h');
    test_char = oc;
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc.GetChar()", test_char, 'h');
  }

  catch (std::invalid_argument &e) {
    caught = true;
  }

  if (caught) {
    std::cout << "FAIL: One or more exceptions thrown\n";
    cumulative_pass = false;
  }

  if (cumulative_pass) {
    std::cout << "PASS\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "FAIL: One or more cases failed\n";
  }

  return cumulative_pass;
}

int main() {
  bool cumulative_pass = true;

  cumulative_pass &= TestValidConstructor();
  cumulative_pass &= TestEmptyStringConstructor();
  cumulative_pass &= TestDuplicateCharConstructor();
  cumulative_pass &= TestIncrementDecrementWrap();
  cumulative_pass &= TestIncrementDecrementClamp();
  cumulative_pass &= TestMiscFunctions();
  cumulative_pass &= TestConversion();

  std::cout << "\nSummary\n";
  std::cout << "-------\n";

  if (cumulative_pass) {
    std::cout << "PASS: All tests passed\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  } else {
    std::cout << "FAIL: One or more tests failed\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}


Do be cautious of mixing strings and plain characters, because strings do comparison with Traits::eq(), which may not yield the same results as operator== for the character type. If you want to store the list of chars as a string, fine, but maybe don’t use any of the string functions (like .find()), and use regular algorithms (like std::find()) instead.

@Blindman67 Its not clear to me what your concern is.  The intent is for the input list of characters to be non-repeating and in an arbitrary order.  I don't expect the list to be more than 100-200 characters long in any case.  Given this I think there's no better option than an order N linear search.  Is the suggestion that .find doesn't do this?

The OrderedChar class looks pretty clean.  There's an cs_ = char_string in the constructor that's clearly unnecessary (simple reasoning shows that it must already have that value) and is the only thing (apart from copyability) that prevents us making cs_ a const member.

The tests could be improved a bit.  We embed type names in EvalPassFailCaseChar() and EvalPassFailCaseBool rather than making them overloads sharing a name.  If we std::cout << std::boolalpha we could even make them instances of a single template, which would reduce the code and therefore the maintenance burden.
It's frustrating and error-prone to have to repeat ourselves like this:

    test_char = oc_no_clamp.Pred();
    cumulative_pass &= EvalPassFailCaseChar("oc_no_clamp.Pred()", test_char, 'm');


We could use a macro to create the correct string for us:
#define TEST_EQ(expr, expected) \
    EvalPassFailCase(#expr, (expr), (expected))

cumulative_pass &= TEST_EQ(oc_no_clamp.Pred(), 'm');

We could also use the macro to pass the file name and line number so we can report those as a prefix of any failing tests:
    std::cerr << filename << ':' << line_no << ": FAIL: " << …;

That makes it easier for developers to jump straight to the failing test to inspect it.
I'm not a big fan of printing a line for every passing test - that becomes overwhelming very quickly and makes it easy to miss any failures.  If you really want confirmation that they have all executed, just print a summary count of the number of tests that ran.
There's no need to introduce a caught variable to immediately act upon:
  catch (std::invalid_argument &e) {
    caught = true;
  }

  if (caught) {
    std::cout << "FAIL: One or more exceptions thrown\n";
    cumulative_pass = false;
  }

Just put the code directly into the catch block (and use the error stream for errors):
  catch (std::invalid_argument &e) {
    std::cerr << "FAIL: One or more exceptions thrown\n";
    cumulative_pass = false;
  }

